# Runge Kutta, Gaus Legendre Stability

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

I am looking for the stability function of the Gaus Legendre algorithm of order $4$.

I already have a solution but im not sure if its right:

$$R(z)=\frac{\frac{1}{12}z²+z+1} {\frac{1}{12}z²+1}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the method to $y'=f(y)=zy$, think of $z$ as a sufficiently small constant, use step size $1$. Then the Gauß-Legendre method reads as
\begin{align}
k_1&=z\left(y_0+\frac14k_1+\left[\frac14-\frac{\sqrt3}6\right]k_2\right) \\
k_1&=z\left(y_0+\left[\frac14+\frac{\sqrt3}6\right]k_1+\frac14k_2\right) \\
y_1&=y_0+\frac12(k_1+k_2)
\end{align}
This is now to be solved, made easier by exploiting the symmetry of the coefficient table
\begin{align}
k_1-k_2&=-\frac{\sqrt3}6z(k_1+k_2)
\\
k_1+k_2&=z\left(2y_0+\frac12(k_1+k_2)+\frac{\sqrt3}6(k_1-k_2)\right)
\\
&=z\left(2y_0+\frac12(k_1+k_2)-\frac1{12}z(k_1+k_2)\right)
\\\implies
k+1+k_2&=\frac{2zy_0}{1-\frac12z+\frac1{12}z^2}\\
y_1&=y_0+\frac{zy_0}{1-\frac12z+\frac1{12}z^2}\\
&=\frac{1+\frac12z+\frac1{12}z^2}{1-\frac12z+\frac1{12}z^2}y_0=R(z)y_0
\end{align}
so that indeed $R(z)$ is the symmetric 2-2 Pade approximant of $\exp(z)$. Somewhere you must have mixed up $y_0$ and $y_1$ close to the end of your computation.